# Requests.post resulting in "TooManyRedirects" error

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Tried to execute the following code but invariably get the "TooManyRedirects" error.  What am I doing incorrectly?

#### My code:

```
import requests, json
Address = '100 W Grant Street'
City = 'Orlando'
State = 'FL'
url = 'https://tools.usps.com/tools/app/ziplookup/zipByAddress'
data = {'company':'', 'address1': Address, 'address2':'','city': City, 'state': 'State', 'zip': ''}
raw = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

#### Here's the massive error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1347>", line 1, in <module>
    raw = requests.post(url, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Users\Karun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 140, in resolve_redirects
    raise TooManyRedirects('Exceeded %s redirects.' % self.max_redirects, response=resp)
requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to pass a list of addresses (with just address1, city and state) through the requests.post statement and get corrected address fields (address1, city, state and zip) in case there's an error in any of the input items (for example, misspelt address1 field, etc).  But right now, I can't even get the post statement to work on a single address.

Answer (score 0):

This particular url, for some reason, wants me to include the headers['User-Agent'] in the requests.post statement also.  Then I get an appropriate response.  So here's the new code:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://tools.usps.com/tools/app/ziplookup/zipByAddress'
payload = {'companyName':'', 'address1':'10570 Main St', 'address2':'', 'city':'Fairfax', 'state':'VA', 'zip':''}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}
r = s.post(url, data = payload, headers = headers)
```